# How to create data agreeing with study results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I'm teaching hypothesis testing at a high school and came across [this](https://de.scribd.com/doc/266969860/Chocolate-causes-weight-loss) "study" on "Chocolate causes weight loss". I'd really like to look at it in class with my students and not only discuss its maths but also what the problems of this study (and many more, but probably less intentional) is.

Unfortunately, the study does not contain the raw data of the participants and since the participants are all identifiable now (appeared on a TV documentary), the author cannot make the data public.

I'd like to recreate more or less realistic data (just for the weight) for the three groups (low-carb, chocolate, control) such that it roughly matches the result given in the study.

The study only shows two figures picturing daily weight development by group and cumulated change of weight by group. It is known that there were 15 participants starting with an average weight of 81.5kg. The weight change after 21 days was documented to be -3.1% (low-carb), -3.2% (chocolate) and +0.7% (control). Lastly, they state "the weight reduction of this (chocolate) group exceeded the results of the low-carb group by 10% after only three weeks (p = 0.04)".

**Question:** What would be the easiest way to recreate such data?

Ideally, this method also works for very different data, so I can reuse it to create further exercises in the future. In other topics of maths, it is rather easy to "start from the solution" and create an exercise, but in statistics, I usually end up just using some numbers, hoping for the best and correcting until it works.

Comment: My strong bias would be to base the exercise on real data from some study with publicly available data. If you want to generate simulated data though, you could do so in practically any programming language or even Excel. Figure out what you want your data generating process to be then generate a bunch of random numbers, transform them, and get your simulated data.

Comment: Are you looking for hints and guidelines or for someone to actually design this simulation for you?

Comment: @rolando2: I wouldn't mind if someone actually designed this for me, but I'm also very interested in how to keep that process efficient.

Comment: fwiw, what sounds inefficient - unlike the rest - is getting *p* to equal .04.

Comment: +1 It's a great question: some of us create these kinds of simulations all the time in order to study statistical phenomena, evaluate reported results, check that our own work is reasonable, and even to answer questions here :-).  The greatest challenge is in deciding what exactly you want to model.  For instance, you might want to show how easy it is to get a "significant" result like this even when there is no true difference in weight changes; or else you might want to show what the data would look like when the true weight changes agree with the observed ones, or something else.

Comment: What's "easiest" depends on what resources you can use. e.g. if you can use a statistical package that offers the ability to write scripts / programs (and many do) then it's quite easy to do ... but if you can't do that at all for some reason (e.g. don't have any and are not allowed to install software on the machines you use), then that "easy" method isn't as easy at all. A number of questions on site address creation of data sets with particular characteristics.

Comment: @Glen_b: I can prepare on my personal computer, so installing additional software wouldn't be a problem. However, I usually prefer "elementary methods", so if there is a way that doesn't consume way too much time without installing more software (which only has one purpose for me), I'd prefer that. If it helps, I already use Geogebra, Mathematica and sometimes (but not often) MATLAB. I've also used R to create nice diagrams, but would prefer not to for this purpose (I have almost no idea how to use it).

Comment: Mathematica and Matlab will be more than adequate. Even Excel would do, if a bit less easily.

Comment: A solution with Excel would be the preferred one, because I won't have access to Mathematica and MATLAB anymore in a few years.

Comment: I'm not proposing to write you code directly in *any* of them, but there's no point in telling you the kind of steps you could use in one of them if you can't use any of them. There's much you'll still need to specify here: Are you looking to recreate the p-value (however it was obtained) or just the sample statistics given? Did you want all three groups? Did you want all variables or just weight? Did you want the excluded person excluded? (unbalancing the samples).  Did you want each of the measurements (looks like every 5 days in the plot) or just the start and finish measurements?

Comment: @Glen_b: p-value should be the same, I want all three groups but only weight, I'm fine assuming the study started and finished with 15 people and it's enough to have start and finish measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Huy, I heartily encourage your interest in teaching statistics through simulation. The more I see of statistical [mal]practice in the social sciences (including medicine), the more convinced I become that simulation holds the key to a meaningful engagement with statistics *at all levels*.

For you and your students, I would discourage the use of any black-box tools. Rather, a spreadsheet that your students can inspect and modify themselves will give them the most proper exposure to these ideas. Also, to teach your students effectively, I think you will need to have built the spreadsheet yourself so that you understand in depth what's going on 'under the hood'.

To start, I would suggest you build a 5-column spreadsheet. The first 3 columns would give the *potential outcomes* for the study participants, one row for each subject. Column 1 will have the weight change that person would (or did) experience if put in the control group. (You could fill this column in with one of the random-number functions from your spreadsheet program.) The next 2 columns would have the weight changes that would happen in each of the 2 treatment groups. (These columns might be filled in by adding random 'treatment effects' to the control-group weight changes.) Column 4 would have a randomly-generated indicator telling which group the person actually got assigned to. Column 5 would use an appropriate formula to copy over the actual weight change from one of the columns 1..3; some if-then logic should suffice. Once you've done this, columns 4..5 will look like (very much simplified) raw data from the study.

You will have to decide how to generate the treatment effects, of course, and this work actually amounts to deciding what your *model* is! By suitable use of parameters entered into cells off to the side of the main $N \times 5$ grid of data, you can even explore how strong the 'Chocolate effect' would have to be to get detected in studies of different sizes. If you have 20 students in your classroom, you can even model a null effect, and show that 1 in 20 trials still (on average) gets a 'positive result'!

Once again, thank you for your work to bring these important matters alive in your classroom — during [Math and Statistics Awareness Month](http://www.ams.org/mathstatmonth/msamhome), no less!